# Using "Ticks" for being able to calculate with DateTime, what's wrong with that?

Tags: c#, datetime

One of my tables has a `FinishDate` column, defined as `DatTime?` (mind the question mark), so I decided to work as follows in order to check if that field is filled in and if the date is longer than a year ago:

```
DateTime finish = to.FinishDate == null? DateTime.Now : (DateTime) (to.FinishDate);
if (DateTime.Now.Ticks - finish.Ticks > new DateTime(1,0,0).Ticks)
```

As an error message, I get that "Year, Month and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime".

I just want to check if the amount of ticks of the subtraction of the `FinishDate` and now is larger than the amount of ticks in a year.

How can I do that?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Ticks. 1,0,0 is not a valid _Date_ and _DateTime_ does not represent a period of time.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: how? I'm using `Ticks` because this looked rather easy to compare "FinishDate - Now > 1 year", is there another way?

Comment: I think is what you're trying to achieve: `if (finish > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))`. Be aware that using `DateTime.Now` is subject is timezone issues.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gTraop but ^^ vc's suggestion seems more correct to me (covering more edge cases).

Comment: @Fildor Aye, because your fiddle doesn't account for leap days!

Comment: @MatthewWatson exactly. In different scenarios, "a year" can mean vastly different things, so the fiddle _might_ be "close enough" in some cases. But it wouldn't be my final solution, neither. It was more to show that a diff of two DateTimes results in a TimeSpan.

Comment: @vc74. I'm just working here in Belgium, using one timezone, but it looks simple and good (just remind to use `finish < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)` instead of `>`, it's the idea to remove older entries). Thanks a lot. You can write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: If you are cleaning out a Database of "old" entries, you might want to consider moving that calculation into SQL (assuming a SQL-DBMS) entirely.

Comment: ^^ You might even be able to schedule a job performing a Stored Procedure in regular intervalls that removes entries older than a year. (Done that in MS SQL Server quite some time ago)

Comment: @Fildor: Although this is a very good proposal (why can I only give +1 instead of +5?), in my current company we prefer having our applications handling as most as possible and use the database just as a data container without any intelligence.

Comment: Well, that's policy. What can you do... Maybe it's still a compromise to create a Stored Procedure and _trigger_ that by the application ... I would bet quite something that that would improve overall performance.

Comment: @Fildor: you have a valid point, as far as performance is concerned: indeed having the database itself handling pure database tasks (like the cleanup) indeed might improve performance. (+1 again) :-)

Comment: @vc74: Sorry I couldn't give you the "accepted answer" reputation gain (you've been beaten by a guru :-) ).

Comment: @Dominique No worries, I'm not looking for reputation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `0` month and day in .NET's `DateTime`, minimum `DateTime` is `new DateTime(1,1,1)`, but just use `default` or `DateTime.MinValue`. For example:

```
var minTicks = new DateTime.MinValue.Ticks;
```

But you can just compare `DateTimes` between them, so to handle "FinishDate - Now > 1 year" case you can use (consider using UTC times on both sides, i.e. `DateTime.UtcNow`):

```
if (finish > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)) // updated from the comment by vc74
```

Answer (score 4):

The [constructor of `DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-datetime-ctor(system-int32-system-int32-system-int32)) with three int parameters is for the year, month and day(what also the error tells). But you provide 1,0,0. That are not valid values. I dont know why you compare ticks, why not directly the `DateTimes`? You can also subtract `DateTimes`s and get a `TimeSpan` as result which has a [`Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticks?view=net-8.0) property.

```
TimeSpan passed = DateTime.Now - finish;
if(passed > TimeSpan.FromDays(365))
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that this is assuming that a year has 365 days. So you have a leap year issue. If so you need to calculate it in this way:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan year = now.AddYears(1) - now;
```